# Query with codeigniter form helper

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm working on a radius search with Google Maps API and MYSQL (http://spinczyk.net/blog/2009/10/04/radius-search-with-google-maps-and-mysql/)

Is is possible to use CI form helper functions for the following query?

```
SELECT
`id`,
`name`,
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 AS `distance`
FROM `stations`
WHERE
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 < 10
ORDER BY `distance`
```

I'm not sure how to add all that using form helper.

Comment: the form helper is used to make HTML forms. It wont help you here.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use database in your helpers, you need access to the CI super object.
In your function:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->database();
$sql = "YOUR SQL QUERY GOES HERE";
$q = $ci->db->query($sql);
if($q->num_rows() > 0)
{
   //Process your query here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to create that query with the database class as is.

You can use:
`$this->db->query()`
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Or you could extend the database class yourself to include math functions.

Comment: But you can not use $this in the helper functions. You must use: $ci =& get_instance(); $ci->load->database(); $ci->db->query($your_sql_query);

Answer (score 0):

For re-usability reasons, i prefer to create a helper for that :

https://gist.github.com/lefakir/e84c22996b1e77436f955c5a7df4d671

And then use it in other helpers :

```
$ci = get_database_connected_ci();
$query = $ci->db->query($sql);
```